# Getting error while creating object space using JavaSpace?

Tags: java, jini

I am using example from this wikipedia Article  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple_space#JavaSpaces

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;
import net.jini.core.discovery.LookupLocator;
import net.jini.core.entry.Entry;
import net.jini.core.lookup.*;
import net.jini.core.lookup.ServiceRegistrar;
import net.jini.core.lookup.ServiceTemplate;
import net.jini.lookup.entry.Name;
import net.jini.space.JavaSpace;
/**
*
* @author admin
 */
public class findSpace {
  LotEntry entry = new LotEntry();            // Create the Entry object
  JavaSpace space = (JavaSpace)space();       // Create an Object Space
}
```

**Error in Creating an object space line:     space()**

cannot find Symbol error

**JavsSpace Code:**

```
package net.jini.space;

import java.rmi.MarshalledObject;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import net.jini.core.entry.Entry;
import net.jini.core.entry.UnusableEntryException;
import net.jini.core.event.EventRegistration;
import net.jini.core.event.RemoteEventListener;
import net.jini.core.lease.Lease;
import net.jini.core.transaction.Transaction;
import net.jini.core.transaction.TransactionException;

public interface JavaSpace {

public static final long NO_WAIT = 0L;

public Lease write(Entry entry, Transaction t, long l) throws TransactionException, RemoteException;

public Entry read(Entry entry, Transaction t, long l) throws UnusableEntryException, TransactionException, InterruptedException, RemoteException;

public Entry readIfExists(Entry entry, Transaction t, long l) throws UnusableEntryException, TransactionException, InterruptedException, RemoteException;

public Entry take(Entry entry, Transaction t, long l) throws UnusableEntryException, TransactionException, InterruptedException, RemoteException;

public Entry takeIfExists(Entry entry, Transaction t, long l) throws UnusableEntryException, TransactionException, InterruptedException, RemoteException;

public EventRegistration notify(Entry entry, Transaction t, RemoteEventListener rl, long l, MarshalledObject mo) throws TransactionException, RemoteException;

public Entry snapshot(Entry entry) throws RemoteException;
}
```

Comment: What is `JavaSpace`, post the code for it

Comment: What is the return type of space()? Can you paste the space() implementation?

Comment: What does `space()` do ?

Comment: You will have to implement space() which returns JavaSpace or any of it's sub type

Comment: **space()**   Thats the only thing i dont know about. it is not containing any implementation

Comment: So, you will have to provide implementation for space(). Compiler can't just substitute it for you.

Comment: @Mr.777 Sir i am using Apache River, and i don't know how to implement JavaSpace in it , i am running some examples from Internet but it is not helping me.... Some complete examples of implemented JavaSpace will be helpful for me...

Comment: I am using this Wikipedia Article as example    [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple_space#JavaSpaces]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66469/discussion-between-mr-777-and-alinaa).

Comment: I have answered your question in chatroom

Comment: @Alinaa i hope issue is resolved now as per comments

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
LookupLocator ll = new LookupLocator("jini://localhost:4160");
StreamServiceRegistrar sr = ll.getStreamRegistrar();
ServiceTemplate srTemplate = new ServiceTemplate(null, new Class[] { ServiceRegistrar.class }, null);
ServiceMatches sms = sr.lookup(template, 10);
if(0 < sms.items.length) {
     JavaSpace space = (JavaSpace) sms.items[0].service;
     // do something with the space
} else {
     System.out.println("No Java Space found.");
}
```

But the service should be running on port 4160. If it's running on some other port, you need to specify that port number.

Also, you can read more about this [here](https://river.apache.org/user-guide-basic-river-services.html)

Comment: `access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8080" "connect,resolve")`   Getting Error on Line 2

Comment: I am Using   `ServiceRegistrar sr = ll.getRegistrar();` **StreamServiceRegistrar** is not spported